# Difference between present perfect and past simple (in a sentence without a finished time word)

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, time, simple-past

In my book I saw the sentence:

> No one was around, so she decided to explore the path.

Could not be "she has decided"? There is no finished time word.

I don't understand why.

Comment: @YosefBaskin but could we use present perfect?

Comment: How? The light has glinted off? Maybe"the light had glinted off, but it no longer did that."

Comment: @YosefBaskin what about the verb admired? could not be has admired?

Comment: Yes, he has admired the shine of his medal.